# Strange behavior of block display mode of views when the pager displays a specified number of items

Tags: 7, views

I've encountered a problem that I've never seen that before (not even in my searches on google). for the sake of simplicity I explain it in an abstract model.
I have 4 content types with a title; they are named ct1, ct2, ct3, and ct4. Every content type has 4 nodes.

I made a view_**N** view for ct**N**, whose display mode is block. I allocated a block on the page p, and view_**N** must display the last 4 titles of ct**N**. I used the following settings.

- Use pager: Display a specified number of items | 4 item
- Offset : 0

Only view_1 displayed 4 items; the other views were empty. I changed "4 items" to 8, and view_1 and view_2 displayed output.

Finally, I found two solutions:

1. view_2's offset must be set to 4, view_3's offset must be set to 8, and view_4's offset must be set to 12.
2. I must set the number of items to display to 16

This is very strange because views and blocks must be totally independent but from what I saw these results are totally depend on each other. I think it is going to be very difficult to handle such independence when there are many blocks and views on the page and each one may have different number of outputs (or all the items).

Is there any general solution for it?

If that makes any difference, I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: you need to override each block

Answer (score 0):

Try using unique pager IDs for each block display here:

[image: Views Pager ID setting]

Comment: such textbox (PAGER ID) doesn't exist, where is it?

Comment: i think this can be solved by overriding the each blocks

Comment: @Bala how can I override blocks?